# Why compiler showing error while passing short values to the generics

Tags: generics, integer, short

In generics, while passing Integer values in the constructor it compiles success, but when passing the Short, Long, Byte values it showing compile time error. To pass the above values I need to downcast the values, why?

```
class F <A> {
       A i;
       F(A a)
      {
        this.i = a;
      }
      public static void main(String[] red) 
      {
        F<Integer> f = new F<Integer>(45);
        F<Short> f1 = new F<Short>((short)3);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A numeric literal without an `l` or `L` type suffix is treated as an `int`.  This is stated in the documentation:

[Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

An `Integer` is constructed from an `int`, a `Short` is constructed from a `short`.  That is why you need a type cast in your `F<Short>` case.